# Transfer image over web request

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms PCL project and would like to transfer a photo that has been selected by the user over a web request

I am using the following code but don't know what to use for the image value, do I just

```
Image image = *selected image*
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"user_session", session},
            {"image", ??? },
            . . . 
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var webResponse= await App.client.PostAsync(App.URL + "test.php", content);
        var response= await webResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: what does your test.php script expect you to send?

Comment: It just gets the image with $image = $_POST['image']; I haven't worked on the php side much yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert your photo to string and then send it as a content of you Post method.

```
 MediaFile file; //add xam.plugin.media nuget package by jamesmontemagno

 var stream = file.GetStream();
            var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            string content = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

you can also use xam.plugin.media package for picking/taking photo. 
read more [Here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#important-permission-information).

Comment: What do I initialize file to? I am getting an error on file.GetStream() since it isn't being initialized

Comment: Check this. [https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#important-permission-information]